# Detecting if a macro parameter is struct/direct type or pointer in C – what's the GCC builtin for this?

Tags: c, pointers, gcc, macros, built-in

In order to differentiate between non-pointers and pointers at compile time one can use macro as:

```
#define IS_STRUCT_SUBSTANTIAL(x) (sizeof(x) != sizeof(void *))
```

However it will fail for 8 byte structs. I've once found a GCC builtin that has been returning different integers depending on the variable type – and it was returning a distinct value for pointers, allowing to fully detect them. However I cannot find it again – it is not at [the website](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html). Could someone provide the name of the builtin?

Comment: `__builtin_types_compatible_p ` might be able to do what you need, with `void*` as the second argument.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo: it was a different builtin. I don't think that `__builtin_types_compatible_p` can do what I want.

Comment: I'm trying to understand why you would need a macro like this. Can you provide an example?

Comment: This looks like an [X-Y-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Your architecture might be wrong. Your last questions all target this issue. Why don't you simply use C++?